# SSD disks VS SATA disks and SAS disks

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, disk-space-utilization

as all know there are many type of disks
while the famous are

```
 SSD disks
 SATA disks 
 SAS disks
```

dose SATA/SAS disks can be nearly as SSD disks? about IO and performance?

how much SSD disks are better from the SATA/SAS disk

Comment: SAS vs SATA is about the interface connecting the drive to the system.  Solid state vs magnetic recording is about the medium the data stored on on. You can have either interface for either medium.  In all cases there is no perfect rules.  You can find crappy SSD+SAS drives that are out performed by SSD+SATA drives.  Generally solid state storage is faster then spinning rust, and the SAS interface has some advantages over SATA when compared with identical underlying media.

Comment: i will be more specific , actually I want to set disk to the zookeeper server , according to the confluent they are recommended the SSD , but there are many types and I am very confused

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to indicate that you've done much research on this topic. In general, questions on StackExchange have the requirement that you've done some basic research before asking.

Comment: what I am say is that confluent recommended to use SSD disks , but after searching we found many type of SSD

Answer (score 1):

In general, a hard drive manufacturer will indicate the performance of a particular model on their product page. I would recommend looking at examples of various drives to get an idea.

Performance will vary wildly between various types but as a rule of thumb:
NVMe SSD > SSD > SSHD > HDD.

PCIe, M2, SAS, SATA, IDE/PATA are connection technologies and only have loose association with the various hard drive types. For example you could have both HDD and SSD on SATA or SAS.